# Selenium tests aren´t launched anymore

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium2, unit-tests, ruby, debugging

I used to be able to launch all my `Selenium2 WebDriver` tests in `Ruby on Rails` via `rake test:units`.

But recently, my `test case(s)` won't be found anymore. I don't get any notification or error message. Traced, the test just ends after `Execute test:units`

It still can be launched manually by calling `rake test:unit TEST=test/unit/foo_bar` or using `ruby [path]` to launch the file.

The test itself still works just fine, so I don't know why the automatic test doesn't start anymore. Maybe I violated some naming conventions? This is how everything is named:

- File: foo_bar.rb
- Class: FooBar
- Method: test_foo_bar

Further I use some additional self-written requirements stored in `test/unit/helpers`.

Might this be another source of problems?

Comment: I've read properly or you really said unit test implemented with webdriver?

Comment: Which browser are you testing with, I had some problems when a remote FireFox node upgraded itself so each time Selenium started it had a dialog asking a "user" to check plugins updates. This blocked selenium running properly and caused all our tests to timeout.

Answer (score 1):

If you use unit testing framework **Test:units** then yes it have naming conventions. You can read more from 
[Test::Unit](http://pg-server.csc.ncsu.edu/mediawiki/index.php/CSC/ECE_517_Fall_2010/ch1_1f_TU#Test%3a%3aUnit).